# using `Gmail SMTP` to send `mail` from my web application. But getting Authentication error

Tags: email, spring-mvc, heroku, gmail

using `Gmail SMTP` to send `mail` from my `web-application` which is Deployed in `heroku` But getting `Authentication error`.

I'm receiving a `mail` from `Google` saying that:

```
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google 
Account **********@gmail.com, using an application such as an email 
client or mobile device.
    Details:
Thursday, April 20, 2017 5:35 AM (ET)
Ashburn, VA, USA*
Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices:
```

I tried all these below:
1)I have reviewed the recent login and said `that was me` but still google is not allowing me to login.
2)Turning ON access for less secure apps.

`Sending mail` Code is working fine in my local system, But After `deploy` it is not working.

can anyone tell me that how I can make my `web-application` which is deployed in `Heroku server` which is running from location -`Ashburn,VA, USA*` to be approved to get login into my gmail.

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you - I am also using a gmail account to send SMTP mail via a heroku account. Try logging in to your gmail account and then logging out, and then back in. You can also try this further authentication mechanism at : https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha.

In my case, it took a little while (some anxious wait time?) after doing this before I was able to send SMTP mail.
You might also want to consider if you haven't already using one dedicated gmail account for SMTP mail.